# Why does xpath inside a selector loop still return a list in the tutorial

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I am learning scrapy with the tutorial: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/intro/tutorial.html

When I run the following example script in the tutorial. I found that even though it was already looping through the selector list, the tile I got from `sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()` was still a list, which contained one string. Like `[u'Python 3 Object Oriented Programming']` rather than `u'Python 3 Object Oriented Programming'`. In a later example the list is assigned to item as `item['title'] = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()`, which I think is not logically correct.

```
import scrapy

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//ul/li'):
            title = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            link = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            desc = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
            print title, link, desc
```

However if I use the following code:

```
import scrapy

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.css("ul.directory.dir-col > li > a::attr('href')"):
            link = href.extract()
            print(link)
```

the `link` is a string rather than a list.

Is this a bug or intended?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`.xpath().extract()` and `.css().extract()` return a list because `.xpath()` and `.css()` return `SelectorList` objects.

See https://parsel.readthedocs.org/en/v1.0.1/usage.html#parsel.selector.SelectorList.extract

> (SelectorList) .extract():
>
> Call the .extract() method for each element is this list and return their results flattened, as a list of unicode strings.

[`.extract_first()`](https://parsel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/parsel.html?#parsel.selector.SelectorList.extract_first) is what you are looking for (which is poorly documented)

Taken from http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html :

> If you want to extract only first matched element, you can call the selector `.extract_first()`

```
>>> response.xpath('//div[@id="images"]/a/text()').extract_first()
u'Name: My image 1 '
```

---

In your other example:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for href in response.css("ul.directory.dir-col > li > a::attr('href')"):
        link = href.extract()
        print(link)
```

each `href` in the loop will be a `Selector` object. Calling `.extract()` on it will get you a single Unicode string back:

```
$ scrapy shell "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/"
2016-02-26 12:11:36 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.5 started (bot: scrapybot)
(...)
In [1]: response.css("ul.directory.dir-col > li > a::attr('href')")
Out[1]: 
[<Selector xpath=u"descendant-or-self::ul[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' directory ') and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' dir-col '))]/li/a/@href" data=u'/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/'>,
 <Selector xpath=u"descendant-or-self::ul[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' directory ') and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' dir-col '))]/li/a/@href" data=u'/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/'>,
 ...
 <Selector xpath=u"descendant-or-self::ul[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' directory ') and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' dir-col '))]/li/a/@href" data=u'/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/'>]
```

so `.css()` on the `response` returns a `SelectorList`:

```
In [2]: type(response.css("ul.directory.dir-col > li > a::attr('href')"))
Out[2]: scrapy.selector.unified.SelectorList
```

Looping on that object gives you `Selector` instances:

```
In [5]: for href in response.css("ul.directory.dir-col > li > a::attr('href')"):
   ...:     print href
   ...:     
<Selector xpath=u"descendant-or-self::ul[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' directory ') and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' dir-col '))]/li/a/@href" data=u'/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/'>
<Selector xpath=u"descendant-or-self::ul[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' directory ') and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' dir-col '))]/li/a/@href" data=u'/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/'>
(...)
<Selector xpath=u"descendant-or-self::ul[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' directory ') and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' dir-col '))]/li/a/@href" data=u'/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/'>
```

And calling `.extract()` gives you a single Unicode string:

```
In [6]: for href in response.css("ul.directory.dir-col > li > a::attr('href')"):
    print type(href.extract())
   ...:     
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'unicode'>
```

Note: `.extract()` on `Selector` is [wrongly documented](https://parsel.readthedocs.org/en/v1.0.1/usage.html#parsel.selector.Selector.extract) as returning a list of strings. I'll open an issue on `parsel` (which is the same as Scrapy selectors, and used under the hood in scrapy 1.1+)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I just edited the post and added an example from the tutorial where `extract()` gives a string. Is this because I am using css?

Comment: Right, what I wrote is not correct (too quick of an answer). In fact `.xpath().extract()` and `.css().extract()` return lists because `.xpath()` and `.css()` return `SelectorList` objects. But looping on `.xpath()` with give you a `Selector`, from which you can call `.extract()` and get a single element. I'll amend my answer

Comment: This part is really confusing, but now I understand! Thank you very much!